# Synchronous and Asynchronous method in an Interface vs in a Class?

Tags: java, asynchronous, interface, synchronous

I am working on a project in which I am supposed to make a client and the role of that client is to construct a url basis on input passed and make a REST call on the right server.

And they can do it in two ways, either making a synchronous call or making an asynchronous call. So now I am not sure what is the right way to do this?

Should I make an interface for this with two methods synchronous and asynchronous method and a class that will implement this Interface or should I just make a simple class with these with these two methods inside that?

What is the better approach?

Answer (score 2):

I would not put both methods into the interface, just the synchronuous one.Then imagine N different implementations which really only care about getting the data. All of them can likely be wrapped into a single asynchronuous wrapper class. No need to force each implementation to reinvent the asynchronuous behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I didn't get your full point. Can you be more clear if possible? If you have any example, then it can help me a lot as well.

Comment: This. As long as you provide some standard methods, maybe implement another standard synchronous access interface, it is pretty easy to get an asynchronous view of such an object later on. "No need to reinvent the wheel" is really the sentiment here.

Comment: Well, have one interface method describing the synchronuous behavior. Write an implementatin for it. Provide a wrapper class that wraps around the implementation of your interface that basically calls a wrapped object's method while providing the asynchronuous behavior.

Comment: @Harald: Thanks, now it make sense. Is there any possibility if you can provide a simple example on this which can explain me how I can achieve this? Just a high level overview?

Comment: @Harald Can you provide an example if possible? This will make me understand better in how to implement this? Thanks for the help.